# Isentropic vs Total pressure

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics

I am  confused between these two quantities: **Isentropic pressure** and **Total pressure**.
Are they the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fluid dynamics, within a isentropic process, the pression is not constant, you have a law  like $\frac{p}{\rho^\gamma} = Constant$, or $\frac{p}{T^{\frac{\gamma}{\gamma -1}}} = Constant$

Here $p$ is the pressure (called too a [static pressure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_pressure),  $\rho$ is the density, $\gamma$ is the ratio of the specific heats of the fluid. Because this is an isentropic process, the pressure $p$ can be called "isentropic pressure".

You have a [compressible flow equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle#Compressible_flow_equation), which could be written, in the simplest case :

$$\frac{v^2}{2} + \frac{\gamma}{\gamma -1}\frac{p}{\rho} = Constant =  \frac{\gamma}{\gamma -1}\frac{p_0}{\rho_0}$$

Here  $v$ is the speed of the fluid, $p_0$ is called the "total pressure" (or [stagnation pressure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagnation_pressure)), and $\rho_0$ is called the "total density".

At zero velocity $v=0$, the notions of isentropic pressure and total pressure coincide. Idem for density and total density.